# Ranking users by badges

Tags: support, badges, users

I'm wondering if there is any way to rank myself against others for the number of general and specific badges I have.  Is there some site feature, some query, or anything that can do this?

Some examples:

- "Would I be able to get a ranking of who has the most Enlightened badges?"
- "Who has the most total badges on MY?"
- "Do I have the most Nice Question badges?  If not, how many more do I need to take the lead?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two queries on [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/help) you can use:

- [Users with most badges](http://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/62605/users-with-most-badges)
- [Users with most badges of a certain name](http://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/110381/users-with-most-badges-of-a-certain-name), which you can run for BadgeName = "Enlightened" or "Nice Question"